# jucs2e conflicts with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, packages, incompatibility, journal

The style file for J.UCS, [jucs2e.sty](http://www.jucs.org/ujs/jucs/info/submissions/jucs2e.sty), conflicts with hyperref.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{jucs2e}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! Use of \global doesn't match its definition.
l.15 \global\let
                \hyper@last\relax
```

Apparently this happens because jucs2e.sty redefines `\global`:

```
\def\global\@namedef##1##2{}
```

Is there a fix?

(Removing the definition above seems to work but I wonder whether it'll break things in the future.)

Comment: remove the last definition (the redefinition of \enddocument) and hope for the best. And better load hyperref after this sty to give it a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very nasty bug in the style. I believe it was intended to redefine `\@namedef` and the `\global` remained there. The (anyway rather questionable) redefinition of `\enddocument` should be patched.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{jucs2e}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\enddocument}{\def\global}{\gdef}{}{}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So just change that line to `\def\@namedef##1##2{}`?

Comment: @lhf Basically yes. But the redefinition of `\enddocument` e.g. ignores completely the `\AtEndDocument` hook on which some packages might rely. This style file is bound to create problems. In fact, I think the comment by @UlrikeFischer to the question is the better solution (particularly the "_hope for the best_" bit `:-)`).